# getting the count of hstore column in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, hstore

Question 1: 
Would **Modelname.family.to_h.count** or **Modelname.family.to_a.count** be the best way to get a count of Hstore items in a column?

---

Question 2:

Also, since Hstore keys are unique, i am storing my values under the following key name schema:

```
"adult_0" => "Jack Johnson",
"adult_1" => "Mary Smith",
"child_0" => "Daniel Smith",
"child_1" => "Marcy Smith",
"child_2" => "Nathaniel Smith"
```

What would be the best way to do a count for each type (child/adult). would a method in the model, where i do query with something like key.include? "adult_" work, or is there no way to query based on key name?

Comment: @ArupRakshit just move ur cursor on the tag **hstore** to see brief info

Comment: If you have two questions please post two questions, otherwise it just gets messy and confusing if some answers tackle some questions.